# When to include quotation marks for cout

Tags: c++

What does the quotation marks in a cout statement do like in the example below?

```
cout << somevariable << " ";
```

When would I need to include them?

Comment: Have you tried it in a program and examined the output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`" "` means space. For example when you want to print 2 string variables separated with space :

```
std::string str1 = "Hello";
std::string str2 = "World";

std::cout << str1 <<" "<< str2;
```

Output :

```
Hello World
```

If you are asking about `"` in cout, it is used to print any text inside the double quotes.
`std::cout << "Any Text";`

Remember the space inside `" "` also a text.

Comment: Ok thank you! So how come when I am printing a bunch of numbers, if I put endl instead of " " the output turns out to be one number per line? If I use " ", the output is the numbers each with a space in between. Does the " " make sure there is only one space between each element?

Comment: @Jasmine `" "` means only space, `endl` means newline. Newline means the end of current line, then bring you to the next line. So putting `endl` will put anything printed after it to the new line

Comment: @gameon67 -- `std::endl` does **not** mean newline. It means "write a newline **and flush the output stream**". `'\n'` means newline.

Comment: @gameon67 -- you should probably mention that `" "` has nothing to do with `std::cout`. It's just a string literal, just like `"Hello"` in your code example. The stream inserter (`<<`) knows how to copy the contents of a string literal into an output stream, which is why `std::cout << " "` puts a space into the stream.